# Is there a way to combine vmax and px value for an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make this work ?

`style.left = "10vmax + 10px"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: in javascript `element.style.setProperty('left', 'calc(........)');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `calc` function in css, use the `style.left` property on the element.

```js
document.querySelector('.item').style.left = 'calc(10vmax + 10px)'
```

```css
.item {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```